# Consulta MySQL com ORDER BY misto?

Tags: mysql, sql

Minha dúvida é um pouco chata de se explicar mas vou tentar deixar o mais simples possível.

Eu tenho as seguintes tabelas em um banco de dados MySQL: `produto`, `preco`, `preco_produto` (mapeamento muitos para muitos), `venda` e `itens_venda`.

Eu preciso de uma consulta para um relatório que me retorne a quantidade de saídas (em vendas) desses produtos, e a renda estipulada que essas saídas geraram. Eu também quero manter a relação do `preco_produto`, pois é pra ficar claro que as saídas daquele produto foram feitas no momento que um determinado preço estava valendo.

Então eu cheguei em uma consulta mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT p.nome AS produto, SUM(iv.quantidade) AS qtd, pp.preco_venda AS preco, 
(SUM(iv.quantidade)*pp.preco_venda) AS renda
FROM tb_venda v 
INNER JOIN tb_item_venda iv 
ON (v.id = iv.tb_venda_id) 
INNER JOIN tb_preco_produto pp 
ON (iv.tb_preco_produto_id = pp.id) 
INNER JOIN tb_produto p 
ON (pp.tb_produto_id = p.id) 
WHERE v.tb_status_venda_id = 3
GROUP BY pp.id
ORDER qtd DESC, BY p.nome ASC
```

Só que isso me retorna os registros da seguinte forma:

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| produto |  qtd  | preco | renda |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| Esfirra |  40   | 2.2   | 88    |
| Coxinha |  35   | 2     | 70    |
| Beirute |  30   | 2.5   | 75    |
| Esfirra |  20   | 2     | 40    |
```

Quando na verdade eu queria eles retornados assim, ordenados por quantidade e por nome:

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| produto |  qtd  | preco | renda |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| Esfirra |  40   | 2.2   | 88    |
| Esfirra |  20   | 2     | 40    |
| Coxinha |  35   | 2     | 70    |
| Beirute |  30   | 2.5   | 75    |
```

Existe alguma forma de se obter este resultado trabalhando somente na consulta SQL?

PS.: Se precisar de mais algum detalhe me avisem.

Comment: Deixa ver se entendi "Esfirra" tem o maior "qtd", então ordena primeiro por ela mesmo que exista um "20" para "Esfira" e um "35" para "Coxinha" ? Sendo isto crie uma coluna max(iv.quantidade) AS maxqtd agrupando por produto e ordene por esta 'max"

Comment: Isso mesmo @Motta. Mas se eu agrupar por produto eu perco a relação de "preco_produto" e aí ao invés de aparecer duas esfirras no resultado, aparecerá somente uma. Quanto ao MAX(iv.quantidade), não vai funcionar porque se eu ordenar pela maior quantidade de itens venda, não vai resolver. Talvez se eu fizesse algo tipo MAX(SUM(iv.quantidade)), mas o MySQL não me deixou fazer isso.

Comment: Como sai alterando a ordem: ORDER BY p.nome ASC, qtd DESC?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, o resultado sai todo em ordem crescente por nome do produto. Por exemplo, primeiro viria o "Beirute" com 30, depois a "Coxinha" com 35 e aí a "Esfirra" com 40, com a "Esfirra" com 20 logo após.

Comment: Você pode por uma consulta por fora dessa pegando os apelidos e usando-os no ORDER BY.

Comment: Se você ordenar primeiro pelo produto e depois pela quantidade não funciona?

Answer (score 1):

Tente isto

```
select *
from
(
SELECT p.nome AS produto, SUM(iv.quantidade) AS qtd, pp.preco_venda AS preco, 
(SUM(iv.quantidade)*pp.preco_venda) AS renda
FROM tb_venda v 
INNER JOIN tb_item_venda iv 
ON (v.id = iv.tb_venda_id) 
INNER JOIN tb_preco_produto pp 
ON (iv.tb_preco_produto_id = pp.id) 
INNER JOIN tb_produto p 
ON (pp.tb_produto_id = p.id) 
WHERE v.tb_status_venda_id = 3
GROUP BY p.nome , pp.preco_venda
) c1,
SELECT p.nome AS produto, max(iv.quantidade) AS maxqtd 
FROM tb_venda v 
INNER JOIN tb_item_venda iv 
ON (v.id = iv.tb_venda_id) 
INNER JOIN tb_preco_produto pp 
ON (iv.tb_preco_produto_id = pp.id) 
INNER JOIN tb_produto p 
ON (pp.tb_produto_id = p.id) 
WHERE v.tb_status_venda_id = 3
GROUP BY p.nome , pp.preco_venda
) c2
where c1.produto = c2.produto
--order by c2.maxqtd , c1.produto , c1.qtd
order by c1.produto , c2.maxqtd , c1.qtd--alterado depois
```

Comment: Ah, achei que assim poderia ter resolvido, porém eu preciso do group by pelo id do preco_produto, se não, não preserva o registro do preço. Sem o group by, os registros são ordenados da forma correta, porém perco a relação dos preços. Mesmo tentando `where c1.pp_id = c2.pp_id` não deu certo.

Comment: Talvez tenha de ser order by c1.produto , c2.maxqtd , c1.qtd

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não resolveu. De certa forma isso me traz um resultado parecido com a primeira consulta que postei aqui. :/

Comment: esquece , a solução vei porque se precisava da "maior qtd" ... burrice minha , acho que não entendi a questão da "perco a relação dos preços"

Comment: Vou tentar explicar. Eu tenho produtos cadastrados na tabela `produto`, certo? Toda vez que eu quero mudar o preço de um determinado produto, ao invés de eu cadastrar um novo produto, eu cadastro um novo preço na tabela `preco_produto`. Então na verdade a listagem que eu quero na querie não é dos produtos e sim dos "preços-produto". Eu quero que fique claro na listagem que saiu aquela QTD vendida e aquela RENDA enquanto aquele PREÇO estava valendo pra determinado produto. O que pode ter acontecido é que talvez eu não esteja conseguindo explicar corretamente.

Comment: De qualquer forma, agradeço muito pela tentativa. Acho que o caminho pode ser por aí mesmo. Só não estou conseguindo vislumbrar ainda. Caso tenha alguma mudança, venho e aceito sua resposta (: